# What is a spinner (empty while loop) doing, and why?

Tags: exploit, ios, jailbreak

I've seen that in [the latest iOS jailbreak](https://github.com/pwn20wndstuff/Undecimus/blob/fb524f5e696be50acd37bbac9a6fae255bb49f8c/Undecimus/source/v1ntex_exploit.m#L352), they use so called "spinners". What exactly is a spinner doing? And why?

Apparently it's "blocking the thread execution", but why does the exploit need that?

Comment: Perhaps this should help [Busy or spin loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809277/what-is-the-effect-of-having-an-empty-while-loop)

Comment: @AndrolGenhald I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of different "spinners" when grepping the code. The one you reference appears to be unused:

```
static void spinner_empty(mach_port_t* arg)
{
    while (!*arg)
        ; //spin
}

static void spinner_nonempty(uint64_t* arg)
{
    while (*arg)
        ; //spin
}
```

`spinner_empty` looks like it waits until the `mach_port_t` that `arg` points to casts to true rather than false, and `spinner_nonempty` waits for the `uint64_t` arg points to to be 0. I have no idea what purpose these serve, as they appear to be unused right now.

There's also [this one](https://github.com/pwn20wndstuff/Undecimus/blob/fb524f5e696be50acd37bbac9a6fae255bb49f8c/Undecimus/source/empty_list_sploit.c#L335):

```
// in the end I don't use these, but maybe they help?

volatile int keep_spinning = 1;
void* spinner(void* arg)
{
    while (keep_spinning)
        ;
    return NULL;
}

#define N_SPINNERS 100
pthread_t spin_threads[N_SPINNERS];

void start_spinners()
{
    return;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_SPINNERS; i++) {
        pthread_create(&spin_threads[i], NULL, spinner, NULL);
    }
}

void stop_spinners()
{
    return;
    keep_spinning = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N_SPINNERS; i++) {
        pthread_join(spin_threads[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

In this case it looks like they may simply be there to slow down execution, by having a large number of threads constantly spending as much time as possible doing nothing. The comment seems to indicate that they may not be necessary, but the author thinks perhaps slowing down the execution may give the exploit a higher chance of success.

Comment: It could be a simple spinlock mutex.

Comment: @forest You know a lot more here than I do, maybe you should answer? :P

Comment: I see, so this is basically black magic that 'might' improve exploit success rate? Why is slowing execution giving the exploit a better chance of success?

Comment: @AndrolGenhald Well that's just a guess since it looks like a spinlock. I haven't actually read the code.